# Bash Colum sum over a table of variable length

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sum, multiple-columns

Im trying to get the columsums (exept for the first one) of a tab delimited containing numbers.

To find out the number of columns an store it in a variable I use:

`cols=$(awk '{print NF}' file.txt | sort -nu | tail -n 1`

next I want to calculate the sum of all numbers in that column and store this in a variable again in a for loop:

```
for c in 2:$col
do
  num=$(cat file.txt | awk '{sum+$2 ; print $0} END{print sum}'| tail -n 1
done
```

this 
`num=$(cat file.txt | awk '{sum+$($c) ; print $0} END{print sum}'| tail -n 1`
on itself with a fixed numer and  without variable input works find but i cannot get it to accept the for-loop variable.

Thanks for the support

p.s. It would also be fine if i could sum all columns (expept the first one) at once without the loop-trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the sums of the individual columns,

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12

$ awk '
    {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum[i] += $i} 
    END {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d%s", sum[i], OFS; print ""}
' file
18 21 24
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're not bound to `awk`, there's a nice tool for "*command-line [statistical operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Available-Operations.html#Available-Operations)*" on textual files called [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/).

With `datamash`, summing (probably the simplest operation of all) a 2nd column is as easy as:

```
$ datamash sum 2 < table
9
```

Assuming the `table` file holds tab-separated data like:

```
$ cat table
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
```

To sum all columns from `2` to `n` use [column ranges](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Column-Ranges.html#Column-Ranges) (available in `datamash` 1.2):

```
$ n=4
$ datamash sum 2-$n < table
9   12  15
```

To include headers, see the `--headers-out` option